# Find tables without data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can we retrieve all tables in database without data (as in, there are no rows in table) in the case of a Microsoft SQL Server?
Is there any method?

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/09/08/sql-server-find-row-count-in-table-find-largest-table-in-database-part-2/

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
   SELECT   TableName=OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) ,Data_Rows= SUM(row_count) 
   FROM     sys.dm_db_partition_stats
   WHERE    index_id in (0 ,1)
   GROUP BY OBJECT_ID
   HAVING   SUM(row_count)  = 0
```

OR If u need only user defined tables then use this

```
   SELECT TableName=OBJECT_NAME(s.OBJECT_ID) ,Data_Rows= SUM(row_count) 
   FROM     sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
   JOIN     sys.tables  T
   ON       T.object_id = S.object_id       
   WHERE    index_id in (0 ,1)
   and      T.type  = 'U'
   GROUP BY s.OBJECT_ID
   HAVING   SUM(row_count)  = 0
```

Comment: Question never excluded system tables.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT   sc.name +'.'+ ta.name TableName
         ,SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt
FROM     sys.tables ta
         INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa
                    ON pa.OBJECT_ID = ta.OBJECT_ID
         INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
                    ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE    ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
GROUP BY sc.name,ta.name
)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RowCnt = 0
```

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/09/08/sql-server-find-row-count-in-table-find-largest-table-in-database-part-2/

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) + '].[' + t.name + ']' AS fulltable_name, SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS schema_name, t.name AS table_name,
i.rows
FROM sys.tables AS t INNER JOIN
sys.sysindexes AS i ON t.object_id = i.id AND i.indid < 2 and i.rows=0
```

It will give table name and rows in that tables

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [AdaTheDev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2326447/456814):

> A statement I think is worth mentioning is [SET FMTONLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx):
>
> ```
> SET FMTONLY ON;
> SELECT * FROM SomeTable
> SET FMTONLY OFF;
> ```
>
> > No rows are processed or sent to the client because of the request when SET FMTONLY is turned ON.
>
> The reason this can be handy is because you can supply any
>   query/stored procedure and return just the metadata of the resultset.

Or, as stated in [Shoaib's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2326409/456814)

> Try: `SELECT TOP 0 * FROM [TableName]`
>
> and use SQLDataAdapter to fill a DataSet, then get the Table from that
>   DataSet.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/43428/10)**

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of empty tables, we can use the below tsql –

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ?) PRINT ''?'' '
```

And, to get a list of tables having at least one row of data, we can use the below tsql –

```
 EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ?) PRINT ''?'' '
```